# Count field separators on each line of input file and if missing/exceeding, output filename to error file

Tags: awk

I have to validate the input file, `Input.txt,` for proper number of field separators on each row and if even one row including the header is missing or exceeding the correct number of field separators then print the name of the file to `errorfiles.txt` and exit.

I have another file to use as reference for the correct number of field separators, `valid.txt`, then compare the number of field separators on each row of the input file with the number of field separators in the `valid.txt` file.

```
awk -F '|' '{ print NF-1; exit }' valid.txt > fscount    
awk -F '|' '(NF-1) != "cat fscount" { print FILENAME>"errorfiles.txt"; exit}' Input.txt
```

This is not working.

```
awk -F '|' '{ print NF-1; exit }' valid.txt > fscount
awk -F '|' '(NF-1) != "cat fscount" { print FILENAME>"errorfiles.txt"; exit}' Input.txt
```

Comment: The `FILENAME` would print `Input.txt` always for any number of incorrect lines

Comment: use diff after the first step.

Comment: @Inian if there is no incorrect lines then i dont want it to print, thats why i put the (NF-1) != "cat fscount" condition, but my syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *not* fully clear what your requirement is, to print the `FILENAME` on just a single input file provided, perhaps you wanted to loop over a list of files on a directory running this command?

Anyway, to use the content of the file in the context of `awk`, just use its `-v` switch and use input re-direction on the file

```
awk -F '|' -v count="$(<fscount)" -v fname="errorfiles.txt" '(NF-1) != (count+0) { print FILENAME > fname; close(fname); exit}' Input.txt
```

Notice the use of `close(filename)` here, which is generally required when you are manipulating files inside `awk` constructs. The `close()` call just closes the file descriptor associated with opening the file pointed by `filename` explicitly, instead of letting the OS do it.

Comment: yes that's exactly my req, i have to loop through a bunch of files input*.txt in a directory, iam using a for loop-- for s in 'ls input_*.txt' do...done....can i use the 's' variable in the awk command instead of the filename ...awk -F '|' -v count="$(<fscount)" -v fname="errorfiles.txt" '(NF-1) != (count+0) { print FILENAME > fname; close(fname); exit}' $s....thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk solution:

```
awk -F '|' 'ARGIND==1{aimNF=NF; nextfile} ARGIND==2{if (NF!=aimNF) {print FILENAME > "errorfiles.txt"; exit}}' valid.txt Input.txt
```

You can do it with just one command,
 -- use awk to read two files, store NF number of 1st file, and compare it in the second file.

For other awk you can replace `ARGIND==1` with `FILENAME==ARGV[1]`, and so on.
Or if you are sure first file won't be empty, use `NR==FNR` and `NR>FNR` instead.

Comment: And when there's more than one Input files, just use `ARGIND != 1`, or use `NR==FNR` and `NR>FNR` condition pair.